# Making cURL cookies work in successives curl_exec connections

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I'm crawling a web with cURL and DOM PHP. The web has a products sections where you can go page by page viewing all the products and also you have subsections for more concise searching, in each page 9 products are listed.

I need to store the information of the subsection to witch the product belongs. I start with all the subsections URL's and the program above shows how I try to get the next 9 products page of a subsection.

The problem it's that the web makes redirects with some information that I suppose it's on a cookie because there is not post traces in the network.

For example: In the ALL PRODUCTS section the URL of the second page is like:

www.example.com/product/?n=2

The first page of any subsection has a unique URL like:

www.example.com/product/subsection

The problem is that the link to the next subsection page (next 9 products) is

www.example.com/product/?n=2

The URL it's THE SAME as the all product section but it shows the subsection products. 
The problem it's that I get the ALL PRODUCTS page instead of the SUBSECTION page.

I have tried with cookies but I don't get distinct results.  Any suggestion?

```
<?php
    private ckfile;

    public function main()
    {
        $this->ckfile = tempnam ("C:/Web/", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $copy = $this->get_page();

        $next_visit = $this->link_next($copy);
        while($next_visit != false){//it's not last page
            $copy = $this->get_page($next_visit,$get_name($next_visit));
            $next_visit = $this->link_next($copy);
        }
    }

    public function get_page($URL = "http://www.example.com" , $nombre = "example" )
    {       
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
                        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"),
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
                        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => true,         // set referer on redirect ,
                        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",               //allow all encodings
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,         // follow redirects
                        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,               
                        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 120,          // timeout on connect 
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120,          // timeout on response 
                        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,           // stop after 10 redirects 
                        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $this->ckfile,
                        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       =>  $this->ckfile,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                        CURLOPT_URL             => $URL
                        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $g = 'C:/Web/'.$nombre.'.html';
        if(!is_file($g)){
            $fp=fopen ($g, "w");
            curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
            $trash = curl_exec ($ch); // don't browse them       
            fclose($fp); 
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
    return $g;      
    }

    public function link_next($value)
    {
        # function that searches the DOM for a link and returns a well formed URL
            # or returns false if doesn't find one( last page)
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make multiple calls you want to use curl multi:

```
$ch = curl_multi_init();
```

Not

```
    $ch = curl_init();
```

See this post for an example [Multiple PHP cUrl posts to same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368603/multiple-php-curl-posts-to-same-page)

Comment: I thought that was for making concurrent calls. Do I really need that?

Comment: @beerLantern  I've never got the regular curl_init connection to work across more than one call--if you can, update your question.  Actually, I prefer using PEAR's  HTTP_Request2 instead of the raw curl library for many reasons including this.

Comment: What do you refer about updating my question? If it's something wrong I don't get it, my English it's not that good. I'm actually executing other curl_init calls for visiting the products without fail, the problem is in the next page visit, I'm redirected to the next section because the cookie fails.

Comment: Well... it looks like the PEAR's HTTP_Request2 it's easier... but I have now that feeling of wasting time scaling up.

Comment: Ray, thanks again. I resolved it using HTTP_Request2. I've made an example including the page I was trying to fetch.